# Casting as a vector<2f>

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using OpenCV's highgui include to be able to get mouse click locations on my image. I've defined a vector<2f> that I would like to store the points that have been clicked within, but unfortunately, I think I'm doing something wrong:

```
void on_mouse(int mouseEvent, int x, int y, int flags, void* param)
{
    if( mouseEvent == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN) {

        printf("Clicked image at (%d,%d)\n", x, y);

        (vector<Point2f>*)param.push_back(Point2f(x,y));

    }
}
```

My compiler gives me an error on **param** and says Error: Expression must have class type.
Can anyone suggest how else to cast as a vector structure? or what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: You probably want `((vector<Point2f>*)param)->push_back(Point2f(x,y));`.

Comment: Thanks Chris. That did the trick. Can you please post that as an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: David's answer is better, anyway, since it uses an explicit cast that, imo, actually tidies up the cast a little bit when you read it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    (vector<Point2f>*)param.push_back(Point2f(x,y));
```

Should be:

```
    reinterpret_cast<vector<Point2f>*>(param)->push_back(Point2f(x,y));
```

Comment: `static_cast` should work, shouldn't it? Either way, an explicit cast is better than a C one.

Comment: `static_cast` is for when the represented value may need to change (like `int` to `float`, or between base and derived class pointers). `reinterpret_cast` is for when the represented value must stay the same (like casting a pointer to and from `void *`). In this case, `static_cast` will work, but I prefer to use the cast that reflects the desired semantics.

Comment: I see. I figured `static_cast` should be used when it can since it represents a well-defined conversion (if you get how I mean it), and to/from `void *` is such, as long as it's going back to the type it started as. With the uncertainty there, though, I can see how `reinterpret_cast` fits in.